# Does $|M|=|\frac{M+M^T}{2}|$ hold for any matrix $M$ or only some special $M$, and if so, what're they?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Today when I read some materials on multivariate Gaussian distribution, I hit upon a *seemingly* correct and very simple identity on determinants of two highly related matrices by accident:

> If $M$ is a square matrix, $|M|=|\frac{M+M^T}{2}|$.

For the moment, I'm only sure that if $M$ is a positive definite matrix, the above proposition is correct (which can be proved in a zigzag way based on the fact that the $pdf$ of multivariate Gaussian distribution is normalized). Anyone know how to prove this directly? And whether is the condition that $M$ is positive definite necessary?

**UPDATE:**

Since someone has given a simple counterexample showing that not all $M$ is qualified, to make the problem more meaningful, the focus now is that:

(1) What if $M$ is positive definite?

(2) If (1) can make the proposition become correct, is it necessary? If not, can we give a sufficient and necessary condition on $M$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's clearly not true. Consider
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$
then $\det(M) = 0$, whereas $\det(\frac{M+M^T}{2}) = -1/4$.

As explained in a comment, a similar example shows that "positive definite" isn't enough either, consider
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
This example can easily be generalized to any dimension. The only "general" condition I can honestly think of is "$M$ is symmetric", in which case it's trivial.

Comment: i like such simple counterexamples (+1)

Comment: What if $M$ is positive definite?

Comment: @thuzhf still the answer is no (unless your definition of positive definite implies that the matrix is symmetric).  For example, take
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Let's try with $2\times 2$ matrices; if
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
$$
then
$$
\frac{1}{2}(M+M^T)=\begin{bmatrix} 2a & b+c \\ b+c & 2d \end{bmatrix}
$$
so its determinant is
$$
\frac{1}{4}(4ad-b^2-2bc-c^2)
$$
and equality of determinants becomes
$$
b^2+2bc+c^2=4bc
$$
so $b=c$. Hence the statement only holds when $M$ is already symmetric.

Comment: It's true for 2x2 matrices. What about general cases?

Comment: @thuzhf I think you can find non symmetric examples in higher dimension

Comment: @thuzhf A trivial example in dimension $3$ is any antisymmetric matrix, which has determinant $0$.